# Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearContents' of undefined importCSVFromGmail @ Code.gs:16

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to use this appscript, has been working for me all the time but suddenly I get this error message. Anyone has an idea on why?

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"XXXXXX"');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
 var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0]; 
 attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();

 // Is the attachment a CSV file
var fileName = attachment.getName().toUpperCase().split(".");
if (fileName.length > 1 && fileName[1] == "CSV") 

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXXX");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

  // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
   sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
   sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

 GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(message);
 
 
 }
```

Comment: Which error message are you getting?

Comment: You lost the curly braces `{...}` for the `if` expression. Now you have `var sheet = ...` is executed only if `if` = **true**, but if **false** the variable `sheet` is not defined. This is written in the error